# glibc detected ./.a.out: free(): invalid pointer

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

```
typedef struct _PERSON
{
        size_t age;
        unsigned char* name;
}PERSON;

int init(PERSON** person)
{
        (* person) = (PERSON *) malloc(sizeof(struct _PERSON));
        (* person)->age = 1;
        (* person)->name = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(4));
        (* person)->name = "NAME";

        return 0;
}

void close(PERSON** person)
{
        (* person)->age = 0;
        if((* person)->name != NULL)
        {
                free((* person)->name);
        }

        if((* person) != NULL)
        {
                free((* person));
        }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        PERSON* p;

        init(&p);

        printf("%d\t%s\n", (int) p->age, p->name);

        close(&p);

        return 0;
}
```

```
1       NAME
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000040079c ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x774b6)[0x7fa9027054b6]
/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x73)[0x7fa90270bc83]
./a.out(close+0x3d)[0x400651]
./a.out[0x40069f]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfe)[0x7fa9026acd8e]
./a.out[0x4004f9]

...

7fa8fc000000-7fa8fc021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fa8fc021000-7fa900000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7fa902478000-7fa90248d000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 23068732                   /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7fa90248d000-7fa90268c000 ---p 00015000 08:12 23068732                   /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7fa90268c000-7fa90268d000 r--p 00014000 08:12 23068732                   /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7fa90268d000-7fa90268e000 rw-p 00015000 08:12 23068732                   /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7fa90268e000-7fa902808000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 23068970                   /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
7fa902808000-7fa902a07000 ---p 0017a000 08:12 23068970                   /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
7fa902a07000-7fa902a0b000 r--p 00179000 08:12 23068970                   /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
7fa902a0b000-7fa902a0c000 rw-p 0017d000 08:12 23068970                   /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
7fa902a0c000-7fa902a11000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fa902a11000-7fa902a31000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 23068966                   /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
7fa902c25000-7fa902c28000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fa902c2e000-7fa902c31000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fa902c31000-7fa902c32000 r--p 00020000 08:12 23068966                   /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
7fa902c32000-7fa902c33000 rw-p 00021000 08:12 23068966                   /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
7fa902c33000-7fa902c34000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fff442d5000-7fff442f6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff44308000-7fff44309000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(* person)->name = (unsigned char ) malloc(sizeof(4)); (* person)->name = "NAME"`

Here you request the memory and then lose the pointer to that memory. (You point it to "NAME" which wasn't allocated by `malloc`.) That's why when you try to `free` the pointer you get an error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this statement `( *person)->name = "NAME";`. This *does not* copy the string `"NAME"` to variable `name`. Instead it makes `name` point to to another memory location(not the one `malloc` by you). If you try to `free` this memory you will get undefined behavior. You need to use `strcpy` (or `strncpy`) to copy the string into variable `name`. Currently you are doing `malloc(sizeof(4))`, which is not correct. Remember that you need to allocate no.of characters + 1 characters for strings to accomodate the NULL character at the end, currently you have allocated only 4 chars which is not sufficient, you need to allocate memory for 5 chars. So you need to do `malloc(sizeof(char)*5)`.

Comment: If you have a POSIX compliant library (such as glibc), you could use _strdup()_ instead of _malloc()_ + _strcpy()_.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at calloc: 
[calloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc)

Allows you to allocate n members of a stated size. Perhaps it helps thinking about the problem.