# Can't assign string to pointer inside struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Here is a piece of my code, I tried to make it simpler I am trying to assign a string to a pointer inside a struct that is inside an array, also I would like to initialize pointers to NULL so I can check whether or not there is already a doctor using the room...
I keep getting seg fault errors
I would appreciate any help

```
struct appointment{
    char *SSN;
    int status;//is appointment already taken?
};

struct room{
    int doctorID;
    char *doctorname;
    struct appointment hours[10];
};

struct room clinic[5];

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){    //I was trying to initialize all pointers to NULL but didn't work
    clinic[i].doctorID = 0;
    for(int j = 0; i < 10; i++){
        clinic[i].hours[j].status = 0;
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    clinic[i].doctorname = malloc(sizeof(char) * 30); // Am I doing something wrong here?
    *clinic[i].doctorname = "fernando";
    printf("the name of the doctor on clinic %d is %s\n", i, clinic[i].doctorname
    free(consultorios[i].medico);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: and also on your malloc... sizeof(char) is 1; so no need.

Comment: I've found a mistake, it's probably not related but I might as well post it anyway: `for(int j = 0; i < 10; i++)` has `i`s instead of `j`s.

Comment: Thanks David, it was my mistake.. you are right... but still I am getting an error when I try to free(clinic[i]doctorname) it says Invalid pointer. Anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to assign a string user `strcpy` instead.

Change your line

```
*clinic[i].doctorname = "fernando";
```

to

```
strcpy(clinic[i].doctorname, "fernando");
```

Comment: yeah I was just making that comment, your assignment after the malloc will leak the malloc'ed buffer

Comment: Is there a way to free the buffer? because I am getting "invalid pointer" when I try to free it using free(). Anyways thank you for the advice!, I will do it the way you say. But I should keep the malloc line and free the memory after that right? sorry, I am a newbie

Comment: You should be able to free it using `free()`, when you are done with its use. Just to point out, your code has `free(consultorios[i].medico);` which is not freeing `.doctorname`, that might be issue.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry.. my original code is in spanish so I had to translate it to make it more readeble but if I use free(clinic[i].doctorname) is complaining about it being an Invalid pointer and the error is in the function free()

Comment: @user2489371, Not sure why that happens with current code. Make sure you are not writing more characters than you allocated.

Comment: OK, thanks for the help, that improved a lot! in fact I took out the free() part and placed it on a separate for loop... and I am still getting the same error.. I'll see what I can do.. thanks!

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075092/glibc-detected-a-out-free-invalid-pointer I was still using clinic[i].doctorname = "fernado"... shame on me :(.Thanks guys! you are great!!